# How to use strstr with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, referer, strstr

I'm using php to make it so that incoming traffic to my website will append information depending on the search engine.  I'm setting $_SESSION['kw'], if it's not already set, to tel me that it's seo and to append the search terms:

```
  if (isset($result['q']))
   $_SESSION['kw'] = 'seo-'.str_replace('\\"',"X",$result['q']);

  elseif (isset($result['p']))
   $_SESSION['kw'] = 'seo-'.$result['p'];

else {some other stuff}
```

q is what google, msn and ask use for their queries, p is for yahoo.  That covers most of the incoming traffic.  OK so now I want to change it a bit so that if the referring page is yahoo, it appends a Y, if it's google a G, msn M etc.

I tried:

```
if (isset($result['q'])& strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'google'))
   $_SESSION['kw'] = 'seo-G-'.str_replace('\\"',"X",$result['q']);

elseif (isset($result['q'])& !strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'google'))
   $_SESSION['kw'] = 'seo-M-'.str_replace('\\"',"X",$result['q']);

  elseif (isset($result['p']))
   $_SESSION['kw'] = 'seo-Y-'.$result['p'];

    else {some other stuff}
```

But I can't make the first IF true.  If I come from ask.com, I get "seo-M appended", but I can't even when coming from google, get it to append.  Am I just formatting it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the & to &&. This is the usual operator for most programming languages for a logical "and"

In PHP you have && or AND for logical bool operations.

& is usually used for bit-operations, which is wrong here.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I get confused by that stuff sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the wrong AND operator, you should use `&&` not just `&`.  the single ampersand is for bitwise operations.

Try:

```
if (isset($result['q']) && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'google'))
```